# Calling a Function Pointer (Syntax)

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

Let's say I have a function which takes these parameters.

```
int create(Ptr * p,void * (*insert)(void *, void *)) {

//return something later
}
```

And the struct:

```
typedef struct {
void ** ptr;
void * (*insert)(void *, void *));
}Ptr;
```

Where p is a pointer to a struct, and insert is a function pointer to a function with two general pointers (void pointers), to insert a integer in a given tree (I'm using void pointers because in this case it's a integer, in other cases it may not be).

How would I go about calling the function create, here?

I know I can do something along the lines of this for the first parameter:

//in a seperate .c file

```
Ptr * pt;
pt = malloc(sizeof(Ptr));

create(pt,....what to put here)?
```

If I wanted to pass the struct pointer as an argument, and an integer to be inserted second (Again they're both void pointers because it is a generic build).

Comment: I think the design is incorrect. You should define the `insert` function, and shouldn't pass it as an argument to the `create` function (as i suppose you don't need to have a separate `insert` function for every node in the tree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside that function, you can write either of:

```
insert(vp1, vp2);
```

or:

```
(*insert)(vp1, vp2);
```

where I'm assuming:

```
void *vp1 = …;
void *vp2 = …;
```

The second is the form that was necessary prior to the C89/C90 standard; you'll find old diehards like me still prefer it.  The first is standard since the first version of the standard was published, but you have to look at the function's argument list to find that `insert` is a pointer to a function instead of the name of function.  That's why I still prefer the old notation.

For actually calling the function, you simply give the name of a function that matches the signature of the `insert` function pointer:

```
extern void *insert_int(void *vp1, void *vp2);

if (create(pt, insert_int) != 0)
    …handle error…
```

Comment: Thanks, also I'm not so sure what I would do with these arguments once passed into create? I'm told to store their address, since this function is only used to initialize a tree.

Comment: There's an element of "I don't know what you want to do with them either".  I'm not clear what your `create()` function is specified to do — because that's what it should do. Without having the whole homework exercise before me, I can't tell you what you're supposed to be doing. There are a lot of ways of writing the code — some of them good, many of them bad, almost all of them found somewhere on SO. I've no idea what you're planning to do with the `void **ptr;` member of your structure. I'd be running a mile from that. Maybe you simply copy the `insert` argument over the `insert` member?

Comment: It's more so the fact that I haven't copied out the entirety of code, to reduce redundancy among other things. Thus the create function's parameters are not fully represent, and neither is the structs field's.

Answer (score 1):

Some compilable example usage:

```
typedef struct {
  void ** ptr;
  void * (*insert)(void *, void *);
} Ptr;
int create(Ptr * p,void * (*insert)(void *, void *));

void* Insert(void*, void*);

void fun(){
  Ptr ptr;
  Ptr * pt = &ptr;

  //Function name decays to its addresss
  create(pt, &Insert);
  create(pt, Insert);  //the same thing

  //Declare a pointer
  void* (*ins)(void*, void*);
  //Assing to it
  ins = &Insert;
  //Same thing
  ins = Insert;

  //Invocation via pointer
  void* ret = (*ins)(pt, pt);

  //Same thing
  ret = ins(pt, pt);

  //Passs the pointer
  create(pt, ins);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the definition of create...

```
void*  mine(void* x, void* y)
{
   return NULL
}

create(pt, mine);
```

and create would be

```
int create(Ptr * p,void * (*insert)(void *, void *)) {
   p->insert = insert;
}
```

I'd go with a function to make the call as well

```
void* ptr_insert(Ptr* p, void* a, void* b)
{
   if(p!=NULL && p->insert != NULL) return p->insert(a,b); 
   return NULL;
}
```